# Viewing Dynamic text in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to print Hello + written text in text box (As I posted earlier). Here's the code I have done. But instead of printing Hello+written text, its only printing Hello after clicking the button.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
public class myActivity1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

      /* // testing add button
         setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);
      */

        final TextView nameText= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.entry);  
        //final TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        final TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);

        tv2.setText("Hello"+ nameText.getText().toString());

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                setContentView(tv2);


            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be an EditText instead of a TextView if you're allowing input?

Comment: Still its giving me the same result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not printing anything after "Hello", because `nameText` is empty.

Now, perhaps `nameText` is really an `EditText`, and you are trying to fill it in at runtime. If so, you need to check the contents of `nameText` in the `OnClickListener`. Right now, you are checking it in `onCreate()`, before the UI is even presented to the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... It worked! Actually I need to go through the basic documentation first!

Answer (score 0):

Should your setContentView(tv2) line be:

```
tv2.setText("Hello"+ nameText.getText().toString());
```

Instead?